# Given a transformational matrix, is it possible to determine two bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm relatively bad at Linear Algebra, so please bear with me here. Given to bases and a transform between them, it's relatively easy to find the corresponding transformational Matrix. However, I am having trouble doing the opposite: Given a Matrix, I am trying to find two bases of two Vector spaces. Is there any algorithm or way to think of this?

Specifically, given a linear transform $\psi : \mathbb R ^4 \to \mathbb R ^3, x\mapsto Ax$, I am asked to construct $\mathscr{B}_1$ as a base of $\mathbb R ^4 $ and $\mathscr B_2$ as a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $M_{\mathscr B_2}^{\mathscr B_1} = B$.

Here, $ A= \left(\begin{matrix}3&-1&1&7\\1&1&1&5\\1&-1&0&1\end{matrix}\right) $ and $B= \left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$.

What I find especially confusing about the question is that $\psi$ maps $x$ to $Ax$, and nothing concerning the matrix $B$. I must be missing something, because at the moment this question seems like guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve the system$$A.\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=(0,0,0),$$you will see that its solutions are the vectors of the form $(a,b,4a-6b,-a+b)$. So, take two such vectors which are linearly independent, such as $(1,0,4,-1)$ and $(0,1,-6,1)$. I will call them $v_1$ and $v_2$:

Since $\dim\ker A=2$, $\dim\operatorname{range}A=2$, by the rank-nullity theorem. Let $w,w^\ast\in\mathbb R^3$ two linearly independent vectors which belong to $\operatorname{range}A$, let $v_3\in\mathbb R^4$ be such that $A.v_3=w$ and let $v_4\in\mathbb R^4$ be such that $A.v_4=w^\ast$. Now, take $\mathscr B_1={v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}$ and take $\mathscr{B}_2=\{w,w^\ast,w'\}$, where $w'$ is any vector of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\{w,w^\ast,w'\}$ is linearly independent.

It follows from these computations that $A.v_1=A.v_2=0$, that $A.v_3=w$ and that $A.v_4=w^\ast$. In other words, the matrix of $A$ with respect to the bases $\mathscr B_1$ and $\mathscr B_2$ is the matix $B$.

Comment: What does it mean to belong to the range of $A$? And why does solving the system A(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,0) help? Is it about finding the kernel?

Comment: To be of the form $A.x$ for some $x\in\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's something I still don't understand. Why can you solve A*(a,b,c,d) if A is a 4*3 matrix? What's the logic behind the first step? Is it just solving a homogenous system of equations?

Comment: No, $A$ is *not* a $4\times3$ matrix. It is a $3\times4$ matrix and therefore the map $x\mapsto A.x$ is a map from $\mathbb R^4$ into $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I see yes, thank you. Could you also maybe please explain the last sentence, if you wouldn't mind? It doesn't quite make sense how that is the matrix B, and not just A.

Comment: Since $A.v_1=0\times w+0\times w^\ast+0\times w'$, $A.v_2=0\times w+0\times w^\ast+0\times w'$, $A.v_3=1\times w+0\times w^\ast+0\times w'$, and $A.v_4=0\times w+1\times w^*+0\times w'$, the matrix of $\psi$ with respect to the bases $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and $\{w,w^\ast,w'\}$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$